# iOS - creating proportional button, labels, etc with autolayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, uilabel, autolayout

I'm trying to create a game menu using autolayout.  I really want this to scale depending on the size of the screen.  For example, if a UILabel has a font of 12 on an iphone, it should probably be a 24 or 30 on an ipad.

I use constraints to make the elements themselves bigger depending on screen size, but the title on a UIButton doesn't scale according to the buttons size.

I know you can create elements based on the size class, but is this the best approach?  Should I be remaking the button twice just so I can increase the font size on one button vs another?

I've actually tried that approach, but when I copy my button to another size class it loses all its associated constraints..

What is the best approach to accomplishing something like this.  I need the same layout across devices, but not just spaced the same way.  I need things actually enlarged to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the font size of your button's titleLabel to adjust according to the ratio you want... I would suggest using a ratio of 12 for the screen-size that grows proportionally. For example a device with a screen size twice as big (double the width) will have a font that is twice a big. Your ratio is 320:screenWidth and multiply that by font size 12.

`[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(12.0f*(self.view.frame.size.width/320.0f))]];`

Comment: If you need this on multiple buttons subclass it.

Comment: so this needs to be done programmatically.. IB has nothing to address this?  I could subclass it the way you suggest, but I'd have to create a subclasses for UILabel, UIButton etc just to enlarge the text

Comment: There is something like auto adjust font size to fit width for UILabels (and button title labels presumably). I can't recall the exact method name, check the docs! (I think it is done programmatically as well but at least you dont need subclass because you can just say for (UILabel *label in [self.view subviews]) { and apply it there, loop through all nested subviews

Comment: Make sure to check the returned NSObject is of class type UILabel

Comment: i thought interface builder was supposed to do everything for me from now on :(  no more programming ever.. i guess not